# Insert RECORD into a table in a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, trigger, update, plpgsql, record

I would like to insert a RECORD data type variable (NEW variable) into a table in a trigger. What would the SQL look like?
The following attempts were unsuccessful:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ' || NEW;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ' || NEW.*;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM ' || NEW;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must expand the record.

I've also added a column list to the `insert` and used the much safer `EXECUTE ... USING` form.

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' USING NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3;
```

Please explain your use case in more detail if this is doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 19):

Actually, you do not have to expand the record manually. As long as *number*, *sequence* and *types* of columns match between the two tables, you can use this much simpler form:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO my_table SELECT ($1).*'
USING NEW;
```

Since your table name seems to be stable, you do not even need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. Just a plain `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT (NEW).*
```

The **parentheses** are [required for a composite type to make the syntax unambiguous.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION)

Ask yourself what may change in your app in the future:

- If the target table should stay in sync with the source table (or target and source are the same), then it's better **not** to list columns explicitly.
- If you want to select only certain columns and do not want to change that with possible updates to the source or target table, it's better to supply a column list.

Comment: Kevin, a team-member thanks you. He was searching for days, and finally came upon this gem. This should be the official answer!!! Thank you!