# Execute dynamic INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE in plpgsql function

Tags: trigger, update, insert, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I have this table that is created every month. ex. **`model201707`** ('model' = fixed; '201707' = year & month based on the current date):

```
| COLUMN_NAME   | TYPE        |
|---------------|-------------|
| serial        | varchar     |
| lot           | varchar     |
| model         | varchar     |
| line          | varchar     |
| machine       | varchar     |
| datetimestamp | timestamptz |
```

Example values:

```
| serial | lot        | model  | line | machine | datetimestamp       |
|--------|------------|--------|------|---------|---------------------|
| 1      | 16_F22_F23 | sample | A    | 1       | 2017-02-28 07:22:39 |
| 2      | 16_F22_F23 | sample | A    | 1       | 2017-02-28 07:22:42 |
| 3      | 16_F22_F23 | sample | A    | 1       | 2017-02-28 07:22:45 |
```

I have created a function to get data from table `model201707` and insert it into table `tb_moldsummary`:

```
| COLUMN_NAME   | TYPE      |    |    |     |
|---------------|-----------|----|----|-----|
| machine_name  | varchar   | NN | PK |     |
| model         | varchar   | NN | PK | UNQ |
| mold          | varchar   | NN | PK | UNQ |
| cavity        | varchar   | NN | PK | UNQ |
| totalshots    | int4      |    |    |     |
| datetimestamp | timestamp |    |    |     |
```

Example values:

```
| machine | model  | m_id | cav_id  | totalshots | datetimestamp       |
|---------|--------|------|---------|------------|---------------------|
| 1       | sample | 16   | F22_F23 | 3          | 2017-02-28 07:22:45 |
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_data_func() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$ 

EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary '
    ||  'SELECT NEW.machine, NEW.model, split_part(NEW.lot, ''_'', 1), '
    ||  'SUBSTRING(NEW.lot FROM (POSITION(''_'' in NEW.lot)+1) FOR LENGTH(NEW.lot)), COUNT(lot), NEW.datetimestamp '
    ||  'FROM model' || to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMM') 
    ||  ' WHERE lot = NEW.lot AND machine = NEW.machine GROUP BY machine, model, lot '
    ||  'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tb_summary_unique '
    ||  'DO UPDATE SET '
    ||  'machine = NEW.machine, '
    ||  'totalshots = tb_moldsummary.totalshots + 1, '
    ||  'datetimestamp = NEW.datetimestamp ';


RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_data_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON model201707
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_data_func();
```

Error:

> ```
> [Err] ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "new"
> LINE 1: INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary SELECT NEW.machine, NEW.model, sp...
> ```

I already checked the following links, but I'm confused:

[PLPGSQL STATEMENTS EXECUTING DYNAMIC SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

[insert-record-into-a-table-in-a-trigger-function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58455/insert-record-into-a-table-in-a-trigger-function?rq=1)

What's the correct syntax for this dynamic UPSERT?

Comment: `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary '
   || 'SELECT NEW.machine, NEW.model, split_part(NEW.lot, ''_'', 1),
    SUBSTRING(NEW.lot FROM (POSITION(''_'' in NEW.lot)+1) FOR LENGTH(NEW.lot)), COUNT(NEW.lot), NEW.datetimestamp FROM (SELECT $1.*) AS t' USING NEW;` I tried this one but the same error occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple problems. This should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_data_func() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$func$ 
BEGIN  -- !
   EXECUTE
      $x$INSERT INTO tb_moldsummary AS t
         SELECT $1.machine                               -- !
              , $1.model
              , split_part(lot, '_', 1)
              , right(lot, position('_' IN lot) * -1)    -- ! simpler
              , COUNT(lot)
              , $1.datetimestamp
         FROM   model$x$ || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMM') || '
         WHERE  lot = $1.lot
         AND    machine = $1.machine
         GROUP  BY machine, model, lot
         ON     CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tb_summary_unique
         DO     UPDATE
         SET    machine = $1.machine                     -- !
              , totalshots = t.totalshots + 1
              , datetimestamp = $1.datetimestamp'
   USING NEW;                                            -- !

   RETURN NEW; -- can be RETURN NULL for AFTER trigger
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I marked lines with important fixes.

#### Major points

- Pass `NEW` to `EXECUTE` with the `USING` clause (as instructed in the answers to the question you referenced):

  - [Insert RECORD into a table in a trigger function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58455/insert-record-into-a-table-in-a-trigger-function)?
- Dollar-quoting helps to simplify the syntax for string literals containing single quotes.
- Replace

  ```
  SUBSTRING(NEW.lot FROM (POSITION('_' in NEW.lot)+1) FOR LENGTH(NEW.lot))
  ```

  with this simpler and faster equivalent expression:

  ```
  right(NEW.lot, position('_' IN NEW.lot) * -1)
  ```

Comment: @Chris: Nested dollar-quotes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

Comment: Is the `$x$` missing a closing tag?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson It appears to be closed after `FROM model`

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: No unbalanced quotes here. The code works as is. I tested.